# Unable to update chrome: updates disabled by administrator

Tags: google-chrome, updates

When I go `chrome://help`/    it is showing up:

```
Version 34.0.1847.116 m

Updates are disabled by the administrato
```

Why this option is displayed?

- How to remove this option?
- How to update the chrome? which is exactly wanna achieve.

Comment: @Ramhound: https://community.webroot.com/t5/Security-Industry-News/Google-Chrome-34-0-1847-131-Stable-Realesed/td-p/103802

Comment: I don't understand the context of that article.  You will have to provide a summary of the link if you want me to read it.  The article does not change the fact a domain `Administrator` could have setup chrome not to update for a reason.

Comment: The context was: released version is 131 and I am using 116.

Comment: But updates have been disabled on your system.  If you are not an `Administrator` you won't be able to update Chrome.

Comment: Yes.. given permissions. Problem is solved..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you are an `Administrator` and you have the permissions to do this.  If you don't then this has to be done by somebody that does.

1. Go to Registry Editor
2. Go to : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\
3. Double-click at the UpdateDefault or DefaultUpdate
4. And type 0 to 1
5. Exit Registry Editor
6. Reboot

[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/YK1-o4KoSjc)

After the reboot this problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Websites kept giving me messages that my Chrome was out-of-date.  But when I tried to update or uninstall and re-install the newest version of Chrome, the operation repeatedly failed.  **Chrome would neither update nor uninstall** (so that I could re-install it) in Windows 7.  What to do?

I saw many fixes online in connection with the registry, but when I went to regedit.exe, as suggested, my registry showed nothing for Google at all (most of the good advice online says to change the Default Update DWord value at **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google** from 0 to 1).

But what to do if there is no "Google" subfolder listed under Policies?  My "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\POLICES" directory only contained one file, "ab [something]".  Nothing else.  What to do?

When I went to "About Chrome", in the upper right triple horizontal I-Ching-like line place to click on About Chrome, I'd get an enigmatic "Error 3. . . " message.

The swell online fixes hadn't worked.  So I searched at my Windows 7 Start button for "Chrome".  I found an old **ChromeSetup.exe**.  I double clicked on it and -- presto-changeo -- it updated my existing old version and now when I go to "About Chrome",  in the upper right triple horizontal I-Ching-like line place, it says "Google Chrome is up to date" and displays the current version number.
  Perfect!

I hope that this helps!